# How can I replace an item in an array with an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

album.songs = [1234545, 43524];

```
const replaced = album.songs.map( e => { e = Object.assign({}, { _id : 123 }) } );
```

Output: undefined

My problem is that I would like to replace my items in 'songs' array with a specific object. It works with strings or numbers but not with objects.

Comment: You used `albums.songs` to define albums and you are using `album.song` with map...?

Comment: Because you've got your arrow function body in `{ }`, there's no implicit return value.

Comment: @standby954 sorry, thats a typo. I corrected it.

Answer (score 6):

Some notes:

1. With `map`, you *return* the object you want the new array to contain. Assigning to the parameter `e` just changes the value of the parameter, which isn't retained anywhere.
2. There's no need for `Object.assign` there, just create the object directly, so:

   ```
   const replaced = album.songs.map(e => { return { _id : e }; } );
   ```

   or the concise form:

   ```
   const replaced = album.songs.map(e => ({ _id : e }) );
   ```

   Note that since we want to return an object created with an object initializer, and the `{` in the initializer would start a function body, we wrap the value we want to return in `()`.
3. We can even take advantage of shorthand property notation if we change the name of the parameter to `_id`:

   ```
   const replaced = album.songs.map(_id => ({ _id }) );
   ```

Live Example:

```js
const album = {songs: [1234545, 43524]};
const replaced = album.songs.map(_id => ({ _id }) );
console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't assign to the function parameter, since it only exists for that function, and it's not like you're dereferencing a pointer.

Just return the object. An arrow function automatically returns its expression if you don't use curly braces to denote the body.

```js
var songs = [1234545, 43524];

const replaced = songs.map(e => ({_id: e}));

console.log(replaced);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Map* function expects you to return a value for each iteration:

```js
console.log([1, 2].map(n => n * 2))
```

In your case, it should be:

```js
album.songs.map( e => ({ _id : e }))
```